# Pesquisar entre colunas Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Possuo uma `td` com código de cliente e em um outra `td` possuo uma relação de nomes de clientes com o código do cliente
Exemplo:

```
codigo | nomes
0001   | Anderson Silva(0002)
       | Minotauro (0001)
       | Lioto Machida(0003)
```

Gostaria de saber como dar um destaque no nome Minotauro pois é o que consta o código `0001` na coluna código.

Preciso fazer isso via `JQuery` essa minha tabela possuem n registros.

Comment: Como você deseja fazer isso ? Como irá pesquisar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $(".input-search").keyup(function(){
  //pega o css da tabela 
  var tabela = $(this).attr('alt');
  if( $(this).val() != ""){
   $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").hide();
   $("."+tabela+" td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
  } else{
   $("."+tabela+" tbody>tr").show();
  }
 }); 
});
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
 "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) {
  return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">

    <input type="text" class="input-search" alt="lista-clientes" placeholder="Buscar nesta lista" />
    
    <br style="clear:both">
    
    <table class="lista-clientes" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center" width="5%">#</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Carro</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">1</td>
                <td>José Ribeiro</td>
                <td>VW Gol 1.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">2</td>
                <td>Maria Conceição</td>
                <td>Fiat Palio 1.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">3</td>
                <td>Lourdes Silva</td>
                <td>Chevrolet Cosa 1.0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">4</td>
                <td>Marcos Henrique</td>
                <td>VW Jetta 2.0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

esse basta você inserir uma js do jquery

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer usando o `:contains`.

```js
$(".search").keyup(function () {
    var data = this.value.split(" ");

    var table = $("#table").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        table.show();
        return;
    }

    table.hide();

    table.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    .show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search" />
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Diego</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teco</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Louie</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleyton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nunces</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: perfeito :3 muito bom mesmo cara

Comment: Se te ajudou  marque a resposta como certa =D

Comment: a pergunta não é minha :/ haeuahe :3

Comment: Seu filha de uma mãe

Comment: heuheuehu com certeza os comentários não são pra isso mas não resiste!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar no Jquery a opção :contains, que é possivel pesquisar o conteúdo de suas tags td:

```
$(function(){
 $("td:contains('(001)')").css("color","red");

});
```

Link fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y1d8he21/